# React Router multiple Routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

Hello I'm trying to do multiple routes with the react router, but without success
basically i have a layout that will have different content
and also a dashboard with different contents, but without success

```
const HomeContent = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ background: 'red', width: '100%', height: '400px' }}>
      Home
    </div>
  );
};

const AboutContent = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ background: 'blue', width: '100%', height: '400px' }}>
      About
    </div>
  );
};

const DashBoardNav = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ background: 'red', width: '100%', height: '400px' }}>
      DashBoardNav
      <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
const MainRoutes = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { popUpIsOpen } = useSelector(RootState => RootState.togglePopUp);
  const { sideIsOpen } = useSelector(RootState => RootState.toggleSide);
  return (
    <GlobalContainer>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <Overlay
        onClick={() =>
          popUpIsOpen ? dispatch(toggle()) : dispatch(toggleSide())
        }
        pop={popUpIsOpen ? popUpIsOpen : sideIsOpen}
      />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Header />} />
        <Route path="dashboard" element={<DashBoardNav />} />
      </Routes>
      <Content>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<HomeContent />}>
            <Route path="about" element={<AboutContent />} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="dashboard" element={<> DashBoard </>}>
            <Route path="about" element={<> about </>} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Content>

      <Footer />
    </GlobalContainer>
  );
};

export default MainRoutes;
```

But I am getting the following error
my navbar renders normal in my "/", and my Home component like this:

[image]

And when I try to enter my "/ about" path, my navbar does not appear and my div ABOUT (component: AboutContent)
neither:

[image]

Basically I need multiple routes

where I have two navbars (one is from the lading page and others, and one from the dashboard)

equally with the content

Comment: Hello @Mykon Spt, You need to replace path="/" with path="/about" as you need to set the exact path of component. Let me know if its helps to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" element={<HomeContent />} />
  <Route path="/about" element={<AboutContent />} />
  <Route path="/dashboard" element={<DashBoardNav />} />
</Switch>
```

This can resolve your issue. Basically switch is used to switch one or more components. so you need to pass exact component path which can refer to exact that specific component only.

For more details, Request you to refer my [gist link](https://gist.github.com/ankitkanojia/90cea58257bb986b69f36cf7f3ccd584).

Comment: Switch components are combined into the switch statment where they actually reflected.

Comment: Hello thanks I understood the situation, but I ended up choosing to use nested routes from the react router v6: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/dev/docs/installation/getting-started.md#nested-routes

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are a couple problems here, including `path` attributes and nested `Route` components.

I find it easier to read the code when wrapping `Route`s in a `Switch` so that it's explicit that only one of the `Route` components will be rendered.

Here's a full example (removed some of the other code not relevant to the problem):

```js
const MainRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <GlobalContainer>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Header/>
        </Route>

        <Route path="/dashboard">
          <DashBoardNav/>
        </Route>
      </Switch>

      <Content>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <HomeContent/>
          </Route>

          <Route path="/about">
            <AboutContent/>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Content>

      <Footer />
    </GlobalContainer>
  );
};
```

Comment: But that way my header will still not appear on my path = "/ about"

Comment: You can put the headers in another `Switch` as well so only one of those will be rendered. Does that work?

Comment: I tried with the switch and it didn't work very well
i'm using react v 6 i think that's why i didn't find anything in the documentation

Comment: Hmm, might be the `path` attributes, should be prefixed with `/` if they're absolute paths (like "about").

Comment: @MykonSpt Is that "/<space>about"?

Comment: I'm getting confused by the react router v6 and I'm almost giving up.

Comment: @MykonSpt made an update to the answer, let me know if that helps or if there is still some confusion I can help with.

Comment: @HenryWoody I ended up discovering to render nested routes I would need a <outlet /> in the component (home)

but I was unsure how to make this structure I don't know if it would be an ugly code

Answer (score 0):

Since react router v4 you don't nest routes instead you keep them inside a component.
[here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic) is a basic example for the same purpose you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I was following the github documentation
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/dev/docs/installation/getting-started.md#multiple-sets-of-routes